# Compare dataframe group by index row value with previous row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

Just wondering if there is a simply solution to the following problem. Take the following setup

```
import datetime
import pandas

data = [
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": "T1", "score_1": 10.0, "score_2": 20.0},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 5), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": "T1", "score_1": 20.0, "score_2": 20.0},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 8), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": "T1", "score_1": 20.0, "score_2": 20.0},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": "T1-A", "score_1": 10.0, "score_2": 30.0},

    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), "ticker": "ticker-2", "internal_id": "T2", "score_1": 10.0, "score_2": 20.0},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "ticker": "ticker-2", "internal_id": "T2", "score_1": 10.0, "score_2": 20.0},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 9), "ticker": "ticker-2", "internal_id": "T2", "score_1": 30.0, "score_2": 20.0},
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(["date", "ticker"])
df['product'] = df.index.get_level_values('ticker')
df['date'] = df.index.get_level_values('date')
```

I need to be able to compare the last value of certain columns (`internal_id`, `score_1`, `score_2`) and compare them to the previous column on that `ticker`, if it's not the same value as the previous one, then output it, else display `None`/`NaN`.

For example, following the above example, this is my intended output:

```
output = [
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": "T1", "score_1": 10.0, "score_2": 20.0},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 5), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": None, "score_1": 20.0, "score_2": None},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 8), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": None, "score_1": None, "score_2": None},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), "ticker": "ticker-1", "internal_id": "T1-A", "score_1": 10.0, "score_2": 30.0},

    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), "ticker": "ticker-2", "internal_id": "T2", "score_1": None, "score_2": 20.0},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 4), "ticker": "ticker-2", "internal_id": None, "score_1": None, "score_2": None},
    {"date": datetime.date(2020, 1, 9), "ticker": "ticker-2", "internal_id": None, "score_1": 30.0, "score_2": None},
]
```

As you can see, I need to groupby the tickers then compare to the previous dates column value. This needs to work across strings as well as ints/floats.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with compared values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

df = df.mask(df.groupby('ticker').shift().eq(df))
print (df)
         date    ticker internal_id  score_1  score_2
0  2020-01-01  ticker-1          T1     10.0     20.0
1  2020-01-05  ticker-1         NaN     20.0      NaN
2  2020-01-08  ticker-1         NaN      NaN      NaN
3  2020-01-10  ticker-1        T1-A     10.0     30.0
4  2020-01-02  ticker-2          T2     10.0     20.0
5  2020-01-04  ticker-2         NaN      NaN      NaN
6  2020-01-09  ticker-2         NaN     30.0      NaN
```